# Set up a git remote through WebDav on an online drive

Tags: windows, git, webdav

I have access to a drive that I would wish to use as a remote to backup some of my git repository. I have two ways of accessing the drive. The first one is using a normal internet browser (where it asks my username & password to get in). The second one is through an option that the drive calls "remote access" which says I can access the drive through my computer using WebDav, where it lists the WebDav address, username and password.

I managed to map the drive in the file explorer using this WebDav thing. I just put on the WebDav address and then it asked me username and password.

What I would like to do now is set up one of the folders in the drive as a remote in my git repository. Preferably bypassing the mapped drive in the file explorer, since I'd have to map it every time I restart the computer.

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you could map your drive in your local machine, then you could use a folder in that drive as a remote git repository by creating a bare repository

for doing that you have to select a folder in your WebDav drive and run:

```
$ git init --bare
```

This will create an empty repository on that folder. Then you can clone that repository by simply running:

```
$ git clone PATH_TO_THE_REPOSITORY
```

and continue operating like a normal git repository

Comment: Yes, setting it up this way and then using it as a remote is the right thing to do.  You definitely don't want to use it as a mounted drive since WebDAV doesn't support POSIX file system semantics and using it as a mounted drive will likely cause data loss.

Comment: I wish it was that simple! The problem with that is that I need to input the username and the password to access the drive. Doing those simple commands only returns a 'fatal: Authentication failed'. Do you know how to access it by inputing the username and password through git?

Comment: This is not very clear in your question. You should edit it. By the way git wont manage your WebDav authentication. You should resolve it in another way